# Ignore files when building debian package

Tags: git, packaging, deb

When I build `myproject` with the command:

```
dpkg-deb -z8 -Zgzip --build myproject
```

It packs all files inside the package.

Is there a way to ignore some folders from being packed inside the deb-file?

If I could ignore the folder `.git` then I could use the git-repository folder directly for generating the debian package.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unusual to use low level commands like `dpkg-deb` to build debian packages - this looks like a [XY-problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Usually, you build Debian packages from their source by using high level commands like  `debuild` which then calls
`dpkg-buildpackage` and other tools like `dpkg-source`. The actual .deb files are created by calling special targets of `./debian/rules` inside the package source.

Depending on the package versions, `.git` is then automatically ignored.

Comment: What about files in .gitignore. When running `debuild -S`, it seems to still include files that are ignored by .gitignore.

Answer (score -1):

`dpkg-deb` will build your Debian packages according to the package scripts, so in order to exclude one or more directories you may use `dh_install -X .git` (adding any other directory on the same line) in your `debian/rules` script.

For a similar information check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451347/remove-svn-while-building-debian-packages

Comment: The answer is not correct, `dpkg-deb` checks an existing control file, but does not call any package scripts at all. It is a very low level tool to pack files into a .deb file.